# <Redirect issue with a signup in React.js + Node (express) + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redirect

I'm coding a signup with React.js + Node (express) + MongoDB.
All my steps work: my console.log() work in front before, then in the back, then in front again.
My "new User" is well recorded in my database (MongoDB) after subscription. So Everything is OK except the <Redirect from React which works only 0.2 seconds. The page 'jump' back immediately.

Indeed, I have a <Redirect during less than 1 second but the page goes back again to the empty new signup. So I have the "New User" in the database (great!) but my redirect in front doesn't work.

I tried :

```
return <Redirect to='/home' />
return <Redirect push to='/home' />
return <Link to='/home' />
```

...

I felt it was an issue about @ or special character in any input because I succeeded in the process with input without any arobase but it seems not the reason.

*React.js :*
signup.jsx
Hook :

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
```

then example of input

```
<Input
    type='email'
    style={style.inputEmail}
    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}                                         
/>
```

then hook + function in order to manage the backend

```
const [userConnected, setUserConnected] = useState(false)



const handleSubmitForm = async () => {
    
    const data = await fetch('/users/form', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: `email=${email}&password=${password}`
    })
    const body = await data.json();
 
    if(body.integrationBDD){
        setUserConnected(true)
    }  
}

if(userConnected){
   return <Redirect push to='/home' />
}
```

- `import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`

*app.js*

```
<Router>
      <div className="page-container">
        <NavBar />
         <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/"  component={Admin} />
          <Route exact path="/home"  component={Home} />
        ..
```

Please note that when the <Redirect failed, I can see on my browser adress : http://localhost:3001/create-account? " The question tag seems strange ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using react-router, I think you can use the useHistory hook here from. For example:

```
const [userConnected, setUserConnected] = useState(false);
const history = useHistory();

const handleSubmitForm = async ()=> {
   if(body.integrationBDD){
      history.push("/home"); //or history.push("/");
   }
}
```

source: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. We tested History, Redirect and we implemented last modules from  react-router-dom and react-history